# “Donate a sum but allow me to take money back” - say shorter

Tags: labels, copywriting

The idea that the donor can take his or her funds back (unless he or she dies or like this or a set time in the future passes), to make it more appealing to donate. So, it is kinda bequest to a charity.

How to say shortly and appealingly: "Donate a sum but allow me to take money back"?

Another idea is to have just "Donate" option but with also "Allow me to take money back before a date I set." checkbox. But this checkbox would appear just if the donate option is clicked, so somebody would not click it at all because he would not want to donate without the option to take back. That's bad, how to make it better?

Comment: Lend...........

Comment: @PhillipW It isn't lend: The idea is that the "lender" dies :-) And lending usually pays interest, I don't.

Comment: "Lend" doesn't necessarily imply interest:  I can lend say a tool to a friend of mine.  There will be no financial implication.

Comment: Is your plan to actually collect the money upfront no matter what and then maintain a balance for the user that they may dip into according to defined rules, like a cutoff date?

Comment: @TomGriffin Exactly. And the main purpose of this is to make it usable for putting funds in for an inheritance to us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the nature of your business, but I see you compare this act to a bequest to a charity.

In that same context, I've seen nonprofit organizations use "pledge" to describe both the act of committing funds, and the funds themselves (sometimes, a "*pledge gift*").

> #### pledge
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. a solemn promise or undertaking.
> 2. `law`
>    a thing that is given as security for the fulfillment of a contract or the payment of a debt and is liable to forfeiture in the
>    event of failure.
>
> *verb*
>
> 1. commit (a person or organization) by a solemn promise.
> 2. `law`
>    give as security on a loan.
>
> <sub>Oxford English Dictionary</sub>

The pledge in this case is a financial sum, collected immediately, as a commitment to the organization. As with many agreements, it is possible for this commitment to be broken or otherwise reverted.

Comment: It does not answer my question: Using the word "pledge" says nothing about whether the money can be taken back.

Comment: @porton Respectfully, I disagree. A pledge is a commitment or promise. Commitments and promises are revised all the time, but perhaps that’s a matter of interpretation. As a user, though, I’d hope that the page fully explained what the terms are so that the text of the button was less important. If you go that route, you have the ability to clarify what exactly you mean when you say “pledge” (or any other term). For example, “*When you choose to make a Pledge to us, you have the ability to set your own terms...*”

Comment: Sorry, but your advice does not help at all: The entire purpose of this question is to make very clear for the user for UI elements mean just by glancing on them. But you instead propose to add a lengthy text (what I could guess to do myself without your answer).

Comment: @porton Then by all means, downvote the answer. I’m not convinced there exists a single English word that meets your criteria. If you decide you are unsatisfied here, perhaps post it on the more befitting English Stack Exchange, tagged with ‘single-word-requests’.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CTA (or *Call to Action*). So I think the best way is to be straightforward and make people perform teh action you want them to perform. Thus, the word I would use is:

**Donate**

That's the action. The specificities of such action should be clearly stated in your terms and conditions. However, if you want to make the action more enticing, then you can add it below the CTA button, like this: [image]

Comment: Not quite what I need: I want two options to donate: with and without the ability to take money back. Your screenshot does not say this to the user.

Comment: you didn't specify that anywhere, how should I know? UX is about information, we can only provide answers based on such information. if you provide partial data, then you'll get what you consider *wrong* answers. This being said, in this NEW scenario you decribe, your own solution with a checkbox is probably the best path